# Need advice on current food intake

Tags: diet, calories, food, recommended-daily-intake

This week I started doing 1 hour of yoga and 30 minutes of mixed exercises every morning. I also started a diet but am a little confused regarding my food intake. Could I get a second opinion? Does this look okay?

- (10:00 AM) Mixed nuts (almonds, dates, cloves, walnuts, sunflower seeds)
- (11:00 AM) Milk shakes with cereals (Toned milk, Protein one table spoon, Tulsa leave, one spoon turmeric powder, honey, cardamom, 8 to 10 spoons cereals (like muesli, cornflakes or oats)
- (2:00 PM) 1 cup espresso coffee
- (3:00 PM) Sprouts or fruits (1 bowl sprouts or 2 apple or 1 small bowl pomegranate)
- (4:00 PM) 1 cup green tea
- (5:00 PM) 2 medium size sandwich of peanut butter, spread, jam or raw cucumber, tomato
- (9:00 PM) Proper Indian food as a Dinner which includes lots of veggies, grain, sum rice and lentils

As I am desk jockey I spend most of my time in front of computer. I am a vegetarian and my goal is to get a balanced diet with good nutrition and lose some weight if possible.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: 1. It would be helpful if you specify your goals in order for anybody to make any suggestion. 2. Are you a vegetarian?

Answer (score 1):

Your diet doesn't look too bad, but extra care has to be taken by vegetarians, especially since you are using a protein powder. Traditional vegetarian diets normally include fermented products, for example yogurt, to ensure an adquate supply of B12. I recommend you join one of the many websites which provide dietary analysis (eg nutritiondata.com), and enter full details of what you eat in a typical day.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the suggestion... I will check out the statistics from these websites... :)